# Calculate time duration in 2 columns

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to calculate time in 2 column(column `STATUSIN` and column `STATUSOUT`) and place the value in column `WORKINGHOUR` as datetime.

This is the code to display data from the database:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrDAILYDATAWH" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>NIP</th>
                            <th>NAME</th>
                            <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
                            <th>IN</th>
                            <th>OUT</th>
                            <th>WORKINGHOUR</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <th><%# Eval("NIP") %></th>
                    <td><%# Eval("NAME") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("DEPARTMENT") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("STATUSIN") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("STATUSOUT") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("WORKINGHOUR") %></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

This is the code on backend:

```
protected void BindDAILYDATWHARptr() {
  String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MANHOURConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DAILYDATAWH", con)){
      using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
        DataTable dtDaily = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dtDaily);
        rptrDAILYDATAWH.DataSource = dtDaily;
        rptrDAILYDATAWH.DataBind();
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

[image: error code]

Comment: holup, what to do you want to do? with what columns? define calculate? you need to be more specific

Comment: @MichaelRandall i wanna calculate time duration between 2 column (STATUSOUT - STATUSIN) and place the value in column "WORKINGHOUR" as datetime format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the DateTime of each rows STATUSIN and STATUSOUT, convert it to DateTime and get the difference

```
foreach (DataRow pRow in dtDaily.Rows)  
{  
  pRow["WORKINGHOUR"] = (pRow.Field<DateTime>("STATUSOUT") - pRow.Field<DateTime>("STATUSIN")).ToString();
}  

// After the rows are updated, Then bind your datasource.
rptrDAILYDATAWH.DataSource = dtDaily;
rptrDAILYDATAWH.DataBind();
```

`(stOut -stIn)` gives you TimeSpan that you can use to get `TotalDays` or other properties if you want.

If you want to save the changes, use the Update command.

```
sda.Update(dtDaily);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, i've try the code, but appear error 'cannot convert object to string' and 'DataTable' doesn't contain a definition for 'Tables'

Comment: please check my updated question, it's show the error code

Comment: @DeaAnanda table is actually a property of a different DataTable. For SqlDataAdapter, you can access the rows directly without table. [See here for example from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters#example)

Comment: Thankyou, and why cannot convert object to string?

Comment: in code `(pRow["STATUSOUT"]` and `(pRow["STATUSIN"]`

Comment: there is an image detail error in my updated question

Comment: see updated code. Use the Field<DateTime> to get the datetime from row.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT'S WORK FOR ME!!:)

Comment: but, when i checked my database.. the value in (workinghour) it's not saved in database. how to save that value (workinghour) in database?

Comment: `sda.Update(dtDaily);` Documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters). You will need to define a `UpdateCommand` to make the `Update` method work.

Comment: can you please help me with answer my new question in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60275249/c-sharp-asp-net-calculate-date-time-duration-with-condition/60275957?noredirect=1#comment106621932_60275957

Comment: i think it's almost similar with this question