# Calculate date time duration with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to calculate DateTime duration with condition : `IF "STATUSIN" > 08:00:00 then "LATECOME" = "STATUSIN" - 08.00.00`
and I've been trying this code but it's doesn't work.

```
DataTable dtDaily = new DataTable();
string time1 = "08:00:00";
var result = Convert.ToDateTime(time1);
string test = result.ToString("hh:mm:ss");

foreach (DataRow pRow in dtDaily.Rows)
{
   DateTime.ParseExact(pRow["STATUSIN"].ToString(), "hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   if (pRow["STATUSIN"] > time1)
   {
      pRow["LATECOME"] = pRow["STATUSIN"] - time1.ToString();
   }
}
```

This is my code to display the value in table:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrSUMMARYDATA" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>IN</th>
                    <th>LATECOME</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("STATUSIN") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("LATECOME") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working is due to the comparison of string data. You can check if the strings are greater than each other but not how you are thinking.

If you want to compare the two dates, you have to convert the strings to DateTime first, then check which is earlier or later than the other one.

```
DataTable dtDaily = new DataTable();

// If you want to compare the Time, use TimeSpan
TimeSpan time1 = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);

foreach (DataRow pRow in dtDaily.Rows)
{
   if (pRow.Field<DateTime>("STATUSIN").TimeOfDay > time1)
   {
      // This will ONLY be the time portion.. not the full datetime. Notice the 
      // parenthesis around the the statement on the right. You want to convert the resulting
      // Time (after subtraction) to string.
      pRow["LATECOME"] = (pRow.Field<DateTime>("STATUSIN").TimeOfDay  - time1).ToString();
   }
}
```

`pRow.Field<DateTime>("field)` takes the string representation of the data and converts it to DateTime. This is similar to `DateTime.Parse(pRow["field"])` but takes away the step of doing the conversions.

---

[See Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) on TimeSpan

> `public TimeSpan (int hours, int minutes, int seconds);`

Comment: can you help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482275/get-holidays-from-database-using-jquery-datepicker/60488165#60488165

Comment: i think it's similar with this question

Answer (score 1):

Change Code

```
 string time1 = "08:00:00";
DateTime.ParseExact(pRow["STATUSIN"].ToString(), "hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
if (pRow["STATUSIN"] > time1)
{
    pRow["LATECOME"] = pRow["STATUSIN"] - time1.ToString();
}
```

Replace Code

```
DateTime time1 = DateTime.Parse("08:00:00");
 Datetime d=DateTime.ParseExact(pRow["STATUSIN"].ToString(), "hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   if (d > time1)
   {
      pRow["LATECOME"] =d - time1.ToString();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, i've been try that code but still not work. The error says :" Operator can't be applied to operands of type 'DateTime' and 'String'". how to solve that?

Comment: @DeaAnanda  you can used the time1 also can be define type is datetime

Comment: but, why the value still null? whereas i have a date value in `STATUSIN` 08:06:00

Comment: not return null you try this i want run the code and return the 00:06.00