# Get holidays from database using jquery datepicker

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've used the JQuery UI DatePicker for selecting a date and then showing the data from the database. I have 2 tables, `HOLIDAYS` and `SUMMARYDATA`. And now I'm looking for a way to get my table `HOLIDAYS` from database. And then, I want to set some condition in `STATUSIN` and `HOLIDAYDATE` : `if STATUSIN == HOLIDAYDATE THEN TOTALWH = '00:00:00'`

Table `SUMMARYDATA`

```
NIP  NAME   DEPARTMENT  STATUSIN                STATUSOUT               TOTALWH       
A1   ARIA   BB          1/21/2020  8:06:23 AM   1/21/2020  8:07:53 AM   00:01:30
A2   CHLOE  BB          1/21/2020  8:16:07 AM   1/21/2020  9:51:21 AM   01:35:14
A1   ARIA   BB          1/22/2020  9:06:23 AM   1/22/2020  10:07:53 AM  00:01:30
```

Table `HOLIDAYS`

```
ID  HOLIDAYDATE   HOLIDAYNAME  
1   2020-01-01    New Year's Day
2   2020-01-25    Chinese Lunar New Year's Day
```

And this is my sample code to set that in weekend

```
if ((pRow.Field<DateTime>("STATUSIN").DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    || (pRow.Field<DateTime>("STATUSIN").DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
{
    if (pRow.Field<DateTime>("STATUSIN") == DateTime.MinValue)
    {

    }
    else
    {    
        pRow["TOTALWH"] = "00:00:00";                                        
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is the o/p that you are getting? Is your code not working?

Comment: I want to set `if STATUSIN == HOLIDAYDATE THEN TOTALWH = '00:00:00'` @Atk

Comment: Okay. But what are you getting with your sample code? Where do you need help?

Comment: in my sample code i just get `TOTALWH = '00:00:00' when STATUSIN == day of weekend`. And i'm looking for to get `TOTALWH = '00:00:00' when STATUSIN == HOLIDAYDATE (from table Holidays)` @Atk

Comment: Okay. I understood. You can do it in multiple ways either in the database or c# code. Make another datatable and fill it with holiday table result and then check  dates in your datarow by using foreach loop or linq.

Comment: can you show me the source code how to solve it? @Atk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208832/discussion-between-dea-ananda-and-atk).

Comment: I won't be able to provide the exact code since I don't know what date formats you are using in both the holidays and Summary data table.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it won't be possible to provide the exact code since I don't know what date formats you are using in both the holidays and Summary data table.

But, you can use the below code and modify according to your requirements.

This code just hardcodes holiday table in the datatable.

```
  DataTable HOLIDAYS = new DataTable();
            DataColumn[] dc1 = new DataColumn[] {new DataColumn("ID",typeof(string)),
                                                new DataColumn("HOLIDAYDATE",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("HOLIDAYNAME",typeof(string))};
            HOLIDAYS.Columns.AddRange(dc1);

            DataRow dr3 = SUMMARYDATA.NewRow();
            dr3["ID"] = "1"; dr3["HOLIDAYDATE"] = "2020-01-01"; dr3["HOLIDAYNAME"] = "New Year's Day";
            SUMMARYDATA.Rows.Add(dr3);

            DataRow dr4 = SUMMARYDATA.NewRow();
            dr4["ID"] = "2"; dr4["HOLIDAYDATE"] = "2020-01-25"; dr4["HOLIDAYNAME"] = "Chinese Lunar New Year's Day";
            SUMMARYDATA.Rows.Add(dr4);
```

Logic

```
if ((pRow.Field<DateTime>("STATUSIN").DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || pRow.Field<DateTime>("STATUSIN").DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
{
  if (pRow.Field<DateTime>("STATUSIN") == DateTime.MinValue)
  {

  }
  else
  {
     pRow["TOTALWH"] = "00:00:00";
  }
}
else if (HOLIDAYS.AsEnumerable()
         .Select(p => new { ID = p.Field<string>("ID"), HOLIDAYDATE = p.Field<string>("HOLIDAYDATE"), HOLIDAYNAME = p.Field<string>("HOLIDAYNAME") })
         .ToList()
         .Where(b => b.HOLIDAYDATE == pRow.Field<DateTime>("STATUSIN").ToString())
         .Any())
  {
    pRow["TOTALWH"] = "00:00:00";
  }
```

Comment: `STATUSIN = DATETIME, ID = INT(PRIMARY KEY), HOLIDAYDATE = DATE`

Comment: i've been try that but still not working, the `TOTALWH` still not = `"00:00:00"`

Comment: @DeaAnanda Modify it according to your requirement.